# react-select use label as value passed to component instead of value from options array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-select

I am coming across a common problem when using `react-select`. All works well if you don't have to pass a `value` to the component, but in cases where you do it is quite inconvenient.

Often the `value` and the `label` will differ.

When I use the set the state using the value (as I need to) then I don't know how to show the label without having to write a function to map this. Is anything built into the library to handle this?

See link to a [code sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-https-40ylh)

And below is the code showing this issue more clearly. Let me know if any clarity is required?

```
const options = [
  {
    label: "Chelsea Fc",
    value: "CFC"
  },
  {
    label: "Man Utd Fc",
    value: "MUFC"
  }
];

function App() {
  const [team, setTeam] = useState("");

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={() => setTeam("MUFC")}>Set team to Man Utd</button>
      <Select
        value={{ label: team }}
        options={options}
        onChange={item => setTeam(item.value)}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try update the onChange function:

```
onChange={item => setTeam(item.label)}
```

Or add a function to get the label:

```
const [team, setTeam] = useState("");

const getLabel = team => {
 if (team.length > 0) {
  const selected = options.filter(option => option.value === team);
  return selected[0].label;
 }
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    <button onClick={() => setTeam("MUFC")}>Set to Man Utd</button>
    <Select
      value={{ label: getLabel(team) }}
      options={options}
      onChange={item => setTeam(item.value)}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I don't want to set the value as the `label`, I just want to display it as the label

Comment: It seems by setting the select value as " value={{ label: team }}", you are resetting the label by the "team". The team was set by the onChange function which is basically the "value" of selected option.

Comment: adding a getLabel function should work: https://codesandbox.io/embed/gallant-lalande-41flc

Comment: oh yeah, thanks for this. I actually have implemented this myself, but was hoping/presuming that something would come out of the box to do this as it seems like a fairly common issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to map it yourself unfortunately, `react-select` accepts an object into the `value` prop.

I'd make the following changes personally:

`const [team, setTeam] = useState(options[0]);` 
(use whatever option you want as the default team to be displayed, or `null` for no default)

Find the required option to set the value for:

```
<button
  onClick={() => setTeam(options.find(option => option.value === "MUFC"))}
>
```

or hardcode it:

```
<button
  onClick={() => setTeam(options[1])}
>
```

make it so that the `Select` uses the team from state as value, and onChange you simply set the team to the item itself

```
<Select
  value={team}
  options={options}
  onChange={item => setTeam(item)}
/>
```